# dojo Tooltip repositioning after content is loaded

Tags: dojo

ALL!
I have dojo tooltip which is connected to an element.

It is created when/after page is loaded/ready. BUT, the problem is that content is loaded dynamically, when connected element is hovered the first time.

Content is loaded via AJAX. And - as far as the size of HTML content is unknown (widget is created, but content is still empty) - after hovering and content loading - Tooltip is appeared, but ARROW does not point to a connected element, but shifted down.

How to reposition a widget arrow after content is loaded dynamically?

Thanx a lot in advance!

**UPDATE**

After some investigations i have found, that position of tooltip Arrow is adjusted by

**.tundra .dijitTooltipRight .dijitTooltipConnector** class height (**14px** by default)

So i made quick and dirty fix for now:

```
function fixArrowForTooltip() {
    // FIX ARROW (TODO HACK)
    $(".tundra .dijitTooltipRight .dijitTooltipConnector").css("height",
            "14px"); // restore to default for multiple tooltips in the page
    var newHeight = $("#dijit__MasterTooltip_0").height() - 14;
    $(".tundra .dijitTooltipRight .dijitTooltipConnector").css("height",
            newHeight + "px");
    // end of FIX
};
```

And placed this into onShow()...

I know, this should be re-worked, but.. WORKS PERFECT :)))

For any number of tooltips in the page arrows point DIRECTLY to connected elements :)

Comment: try use this.layout() in dijit's onLoad after content loading

Comment: Sorry, did not find such a function anywhere in widget objects... Maybe you could send me a reference about this method?